# What is meant by $\text{Ann}(M)$ and $(0:_M a)$ in this example?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the answer here [Is every Artinian module over an Artinian ring finitely generated?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300418/is-every-artinian-module-over-an-artinian-ring-finitely-generated) can you please tell me what is explicitly $Ann(M)$ and $(0:_Ma)$

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For an $R$-module $M$

- $\text{Ann}_R(M)$ is the set of $r\in R$ such that $r\cdot m=0$ for every $m\in M$. This is called the [annihilator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_(ring_theory)) of the $R$-module $M$.
- $(I:J)$ usually denotes the [colon ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_quotient), which is the set of $r\in R$ such that $rJ\subseteq I$. In your context I think $(0:_M a)$ means the set of $m\in M$ such that $am=0$.

Comment: and why $(0:_Ma)\not=M$ in the answer ? I did not understand that ?

Comment: @basas If $(0:_M a)=M$, then this would mean that $aM=0$, which is the same as saying that $a\in\text{Ann}(M)$. But they assumed that $a\not\in\text{Ann}(M)$